# How does NOT EXISTS work in the following UPDATE statement in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE movieexec e
SET    e.salary = 6m
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   movieexec e2
                   WHERE  e2.salary = 6m);
```

How does it work logically? Can't I just say `WHERE e.Salary != 6M` ?

Comment: This will update all the salaries to 6M so long as there is not a single record with 6M salary.  I can't think of why someone would actually want this logic though.

Comment: Based on my understanding, it will take the next tuple in the relation until the inner query returns false. It will take even tuples that already the attribute salary set to 6M. Is that correct?

Comment: this query is written poorly. no need allies, no need `NOT EXISTS`. `UPDATE  MovieExec e 
SET e.Salary =  6M  where Salary != 6M` will do the same thing.

Comment: @Badiparmagi, that question is something completely different. The original query will update _all_ rows or _no_ rows, depending on the sub-query result. Your query will update _some_ rows.

Comment: @jarlh if I understood your words correctly, I have added answer based on your comment. OP please check the answer which is just updated.

Answer (score 3):

If there were no rows in the table "MovieExec" having the value for salary as "6M" then all the rows would be updated to "6M".

Incase if there was even one row having salary value as "6M" prior to the update statement, then 0 rows would be affected.

Basically it checks if there are rows having value "6M" and updates only if there does not exist a single row having the value "6M" (as what you have specified in your WHERE NOT EXISTS statement), and it is not the same as having salary != 6M in your where clause.

This code is similar to :

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *   FROM    MovieExec e2
                     WHERE  e2.Salary   =   6M)
BEGIN

    UPDATE  MovieExec e 
    SET e.Salary =  6M 

END
```

But written in a single statement.

Comment: this will update all rows even its salary is not equal to `6M`

Comment: This is non-standard SQL. You should at least mention for which DBMS this works (the tag `sql` refers to **standard** SQL, not a specific DBMS product)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to update all the records with `6M` where `salary` is not equal to `6m`. If so you can simply write SQL as below as below:

```
UPDATE MovieExec SET Salary =  6M
WHERE Salary <> 6M
```

Just noticed its already mentioned by @Badiparmagi in the comment and I think he is absolutely right.

If you want any `6M` salary is already exist then don't update any record otherwise update all then use below query

```
UPDATE  MovieExec   
SET Salary =  6M --This should be enclosed in single quote                                                                                                                                                           
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MovieExec e2 WHERE e2.Salary = 6M) = 0
```